# Springboot 3 + Micrometer Tracing: Tracer.currentSpan() null randomly while processing parallel GRPC calls

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

The value of `io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer.currentSpan()` becomes null for random calls at the server end.

This happens when hitting the server with multiple parallel calls, and not if calls are made sequentially.

This is the stack trace at server side:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.micrometer.tracing.Span.context()" because the return value of "io.micrometer.tracing.Tracer.currentSpan()" is null
    at com.example.micrometer.GrpcServerApplication$EchoService.unaryRpc(GrpcServerApplication.java:85) ~[main/:na]
    at io.grpc.testing.protobuf.SimpleServiceGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(SimpleServiceGrpc.java:410) ~[grpc-testing-proto-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:182) ~[grpc-stub-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:35) ~[grpc-api-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.grpc.ObservationGrpcServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ObservationGrpcServerCallListener.java:47) ~[micrometer-core-1.10.6.jar:1.10.6]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:355) ~[grpc-core-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:867) ~[grpc-core-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) ~[grpc-core-1.54.1.jar:1.54.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Here is a minimal [sample server](https://github.com/navaneeth-spotnana/micrometer-samples/tree/main/grpc-server) and [sample client](https://github.com/navaneeth-spotnana/micrometer-samples/tree/main/grpc-client) reproducing the issue. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in micrometer as of 1.0.4 and is tracked [here](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/issues/241).

A temporary workaround till the issue is fixed is to write your own version of [ObservationGrpcServerCallListener](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/grpc/ObservationGrpcServerCallListener.java) and then add extra line `this.scope.makeCurrent();` on `ObservationGrpcServerCallListener#[onMessage|onHalfClose]`.